# How to run telnet over ssh in python

Tags: python, ssh, telnet, forwarding

```
       telnet
server ←————→ device
  ↑
  | SSH
  ↓
localhost (me)
```

I have a device that is connected with one server computer and I want to talk to the device by ssh'ing into the server computer and send telnet commands to my device. How do I setup things in Python to make this happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Python's `paramiko` package to launch a program on the server via ssh.  That program would then in turn receive commands (perhaps via stdin) and return results (via stdout) from the controlling program.  So basically you'll use `paramiko.SSHClient` to connect to the server and run a second Python program which itself uses e.g. `telnetlib` to talk to the device.

Comment: Where does that second python program have to be physically located? on the server or my localhost?

Comment: On the server basically, but you could use paramiko to upload it to the server (via SFTP) before running.

Comment: That is exactly what I am doing right now. But I want to send and receive telnet commands to the device from my localhost computer 'me' and leaving a server computer just as a relaying telnet commands.

Answer (score 0):

Use tunneling by setting up a `SSH` session that tunnels the `Telnet` traffic:
So ssh from `localhost` to `server` with the option `-L xxx:deviceip:23`
(xxx is a free port on localhost, device is the IP address of "device", 23 is the telnet port).

Then open a telnet session on your localhost to localhost:xxx. SSH will tunnel it to the device and response is sent back to you.